# Change AppBar content dynamically on Navigation through App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I've got my Navigation in my App working, but I would like to change the AppBar Title dynamically, depending on which page is currently displayed.
Main Problem is, I'm using a TabBarView, to show the main pages, but I can also get to some sub pages. That part is now working fine, but I can't figure out, how I could make the AppBar change depending on the displayed page / sub-page

Here is the main class, which holds the AppBar:

```
class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppView> createState() => _AppViewState();
}


class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> with TickerProviderStateMixin{

  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 6, vsync: this);
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if(navKey.currentState!.canPop()){
        navKey.currentState!.pop();
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if(navKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
          navKey.currentState!.pop();
        }
        return false;
    },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: HeadLine(
            "Test",
            color: white,
          ),
        ),
          body: Navigator(
            key: navKey,
            onGenerateRoute: (_) => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => TabBarView(
              controller: _controller,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                HomeScreen(),
                ChatOverviewScreen(),
                ForumOverviewScreen(),
                CalendarScreen(),
                GroupScreen(),
                ProfileScreen()
              ],
            )
            ),
          ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(
        controller: _controller,
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

For Testing, theres currently just a button which calls a sub page on one of these pages:

```
class ChatOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChatOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PrimaryButton(
        text: "Do Stuff",
        onPressed: () {
          navKey.currentState!.push(ChatDetailScreen.route());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

navKey is set as global variable in my main file via

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Basicaly I want to set the Title of the AppBar depending on which page / subpage is shown and when it is a sub page, there should also be an arrow to get back.

Comment: Read the index of the tabcontroller and update the app bar text accordingly to the index

Comment: That would work, but only for the "main" pages. But I also want to change it for the sub-pages, which would not work by purely using the index of the tabcontroller.

Comment: You can use e.g provider as statemangement. This way you sent the value as per current screen to the change notifier which updates the reader on the main screen

Comment: Ah, yes. Was able to solve this by using a cubit to store title of the appbar and if the back button should be shown :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
Widget _buildAppBarTitle(int index) {
  String title = '';

  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      title = 'YOUR TITLE';
      break;
    ... other case...
  }
  return Text(title);
}

Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: _buildAppBarTitle(_currentIndex),
  ),
  body: Navigator(
    ...
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    onTap: (index) {
      setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
      });
    },
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,   
    items: [...],
  ),
)
```

You can use enum to identify the pages, also, you can use some state manager.
[Flutter State management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)